# avoiding white spaces between consecutives minipages

Tags: spacing, minipage

I am using the list environment `\begin{itemize}\end{itemize}` in pdflatex with several `\item` inside. I want to make each line from inside the environment "itemize" longer so that the length is `1.25\linewidth`. I used for this the `\begin{minipage}\end{minipage}` command, e.g.

```
\section*{Section 1} 
\begin{minipage}[t][1.2in]{1.25\linewidth} 
\begin{itemize} 
\item here some text in Section 1
\item here some more text Section 1
\item here even some more text Section 1
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage} 


\section*{Section 2}
\begin{minipage}[t][1.2in]{1.25\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item here some text Section 2
\item here some more text Section 2
\item here even some more text Section 2
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
```

Still, between the two sections I have a lot of extra white space. How can I avoid this white space between the 2 minipages? Is there some other way to make each line from inside the itemize environment longer than to use minipage?

Thank you in advance for your help and suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

don't define a height for the minipages!

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{1.25\linewidth}
```